# Type Error: $(......).fancybox is not found

Tags: jquery

It shows a error as

> TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function

in jQuery even if code runs correctly. because of that error other functions of bootstrap are not working properly.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM submit_menuscript_master WHERE edit_panel=''") or die (mysql_error ());
//$info=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<div class="widget-body">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable"  id="sample_1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="hidden" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_1 .checkboxes" /></th>
        <th>Sr. No</th>
        <th>Author Name</th>
        <th>Article Type</th>
        <th>Paper Title</th>
        <th>Submission Date</th>
        <th>&nbsp; </th>
        <th>&nbsp; </th>
        <th>&nbsp; </th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $i=1;
    while($info=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $popupNm="popupDemo_".$info['id'];
    $popupNm1="ab_popup".$info['id'];

    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="check_list_<?php echo $i;?>" id="check_list_<?php echo $i;?>" class="checkboxes" value="<?php echo $info['id']?>" /></td>
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo givedata("pi_login_det","id",$info['auther_id'],"person_name");?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info['type_name'];?></td>                                                                                                                       <td><a class="tooltips" data-original-title="<? echo $info['paper_title'];?>" data-placement="top" ><?php 
        $string= $info['paper_title'];
        if(strlen($string)>=5)
        $string1=substr($string,0,30);
        echo $string1;
        ?></a></td>
        <td><?=date("d-m-Y",strtotime($info['sub_date']));?></td>
        <td><a href="show_absract.php?id=<?php echo $info['id']?>" class="popupCls ab_popup btn btn-info" id="<?php echo $popupNm1;?>">Info</a></td>
        <script>
        $("#<?php echo $popupNm1;?>").fancybox({
            'width'             : '80%',
            'height'            : '100%',
            'hideOnOverlayClick' : false
            });
        </script>
        <td><input type="hidden" id="edit_panel_<?php echo $i;?>" name="edit_panel_<?php echo $i;?>"/><a href="add_editorial_panel.php?i=<?php echo $i;?>&type_name=<?php echo $info['type_name']?>" class="popupCls btn btn-success" id="<?php echo $popupNm;?>">Panel</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <script>
        $("#<?php echo $popupNm;?>").fancybox({
            'width'             : '80%',
            'height'            : '100%',
            'hideOnOverlayClick' : false
            });
        </script>   </td>

        <td><a style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-success" onclick="getPanel(<?php echo $i;?>);">Issue</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  <?php
     $i++;
     }
     ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please post the code where it is giving error. So that I can get an idea.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask and how to format your code. Right now there is NOTHING in the code that generates the error. You need to load jQuery and fancybox in that order and you are not showing that part

Comment: Here is what you are not showing: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox `<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>`